# Skip all Errors While Iteration in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to Data from one workbook and paste it in other while doing so there are some values not searchable, an error is shown. On handling the error it skips the iteration but when the second-time error occurs it is not skipping the iteration but giving the error message.

```
For i = 1 To lrow

    On Error GoTo InvalidValue
    mWkb.Activate
    Sheets("Sheet2").Select
    s_value = ActiveCell.Offset(i, 0).Value

    Sheets("LocDB").Select
    Range("G2").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select

    Selection.Find(What:=s_value, After:= _
                   ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                   SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate


    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Selection.Copy

    wkb.Activate

    Range("G9").Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(i, 0).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
                           :=False, Transpose:=False

InvalidValue:

Next i
```

Comment: Handle the errors; don't skip over them. What's mWkb?

Comment: VBA only applies the on error to the subsequent line, so you would want that before each line you want it run

Comment: mWkb is workbook from where data is searched

Comment: Okay then, good luck with your project!

Comment: @Jeeped - I can feel the sarcasm & the irony here ...

Comment: @Jeeped  I am new to VBA, I am learning, though I got your point finding a way to handle the error. Thank you

Comment: Is the error being caused by the item not being "found"?  Where exactly is the error happening?

Comment: You can get the return value of the `Find` command (in a `Range` object), and then check if the object = `Nothing`.

Comment: W@ashleedawg yes, the error is happening when an item is not found, for the first time it skips the iteration but when the second time value is not found, it throws an error. Runtime error 91, object variable not set

Comment: You setup an error handler but never get out of it. Take a look here: http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/ErrorHandling.htm

Comment: I'd suggest you try to adapt the example from the [documentation for Find](https://msdn.microsoft.com/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-find-method-excel) to your data, and start very simple, then add in more code as it's working.

Comment: You did not supply the entire code

Comment: You'll notice several differences between the example on that page and your code.

Comment: @Davesexcel there's not necessary a need for more code.  Nor error handling, if the `Find` function is used properly.

Comment: Declare your .find return as a Range (maybe **Found**) then use **If Found is Not Nothing Then** > paste data.

Comment: @ashleedawg, the OP is running the code from a different workbook, it would be nice to see how the variables were set

Comment: @Davesexcel - Careful what you wish for! If OP goes to the trouble of posting more, I hope you'll stick with it because I won't be... I was about to ask for **less** code (as per **[MCVE]**) because the error isn't elsewhere, it's in basic use of the `Find` function.  IMHO the OP should figure out how to use that first, and then start adding more code in.  (again, MCVE)  More times than not, the process of reducing code helps OPs find the problem on their own.  "More code" is a dangerous thing to ask for because to many people that means "ooh I'll send my whole file and this guys will fix it!"

Comment: @ashleedawg, thank you so much, i changed the code according to the documentation and its working fine..

Comment: **That's great news!**  If there was only one tip I could give about learning VBA, it's *learn effective Googling*. It sounds silly but with all the crap online it's easy to get distracted by incorrect information or solutions that don't work.  Anything you want to know how to do or fix with VBA, first google it but **add the terms:** "vba msdn", so for example in this case I googled: `vba msdn excel find no match` ... MSDN is the Microsoft Developers Network, so good for VBA but *not* for general Excel questions.  For those I use `excel office.com my question here`. Coders live off of Google!

Comment: @ashleedawg, thank you for guiding me, the information you provided is really a great help for me :) thank you once again

Comment: @aspan88 You're welcome.  This place has a definite learning curve and it can be tricky at first (I've been here under a year so I remember it well). Just about 10 million well-wishing members here - it can be overwhelming sometimes!